# BigQuery - How to iterate over results using java API

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am trying to download a query result of 90k rows (this amount states the web UI and the resulting object) but I obtain more than 130k items in the iterator as follows:

```
QueryRequest queryRequest = QueryRequest
                                        .newBuilder("......")
                                        .setUseLegacySql(true)
                                        .build();
QueryResponse response = bigquery.query(queryRequest);
QueryResult result = response.getResult();
Integer c = 0;

while(result != null){
          Iterator<List<FieldValue>> iter = result.iterateAll();
          while(iter.hasNext()){
              iter.next();
              c++;
            }    
          result = result.getNextPage();
}
```

At the end of the reading is about 130K but `reuslt.getTotalRows()` contains 90K.

Do you have any idea on what I'am doing not correctly?

Comment: I think you've hit some sort of bug. I can reproduce. It's strange. Also, setting the `setPageSize()` parameter makes it even worse - for example, I issued a query with a `limit` of 5K results, `setPageSize(1000L)`, and it iterated 15K times. I think the bug is in the `getNextPage()` method. Your code looks good as per --> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/bigquery/SimpleApp.java. I've raised an issue to see if the Google guys can clarify --> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/issues/506

Comment: Thanks! Just integrated your issue on github. I've noticed google guys are switching to a non legacy sQL standard.

Answer (score 3):

From [JavaDoc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/Page.java#L62), Page.iterateAll() returns results from all pages.

You get all results (from the first page), then advance to the next page, where you get all results again (minus the first page). Setting the page size to a smaller number actually increases the results you get.

Your code should look like this:

```
QueryRequest queryRequest = QueryRequest
                                    .newBuilder("......")
                                    .setUseLegacySql(true)
                                    .build();
QueryResponse response = bigquery.query(queryRequest);
QueryResult result = response.getResult();
Integer c = 0;

Iterator<List<FieldValue>> iter = result.iterateAll();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    iter.next();
    c++;
}
```

Comment: just checked, you are right, big query examples are not so clear.